# What javascript include files are needed to get layout extensions to work in cytoscape?

Tags: javascript, charts, cytoscape.js

Cytoscape Javascript graphing software comes with several built in layouts, but also other layouts that are created as 'extensions'.   I tried to use the 'klay' layout, which is an extension, and I just get JavaScript errors.   (the code I have works fine with built in layouts such as 'cose', but fails with extensions.   Here are the include files I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.14.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/klayjs@0.4.1/klay.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cytoscape-klay.js"></script>
```

So what am I doing wrong here?     Once I have the correct 'include' files, the code should work, because the use of layouts should be the same for built-in layouts as extension layouts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [demo](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-klay), I got it to work just fine like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    // demo your layout
    layout: {
      name: "klay"

      // some more options here...
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          "background-color": "#dd4de2"
        }
      },

      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "line-color": "#dd4de2",
          "target-arrow-color": "#dd4de2",
          opacity: 0.5
        }
      }
    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: "n0"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n11"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n15"
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: "n0",
            target: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n2",
            target: "n4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n10",
            target: "n11"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n11",
            target: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n12",
            target: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n15"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/klayjs@0.4.1/klay.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-klay@3.1.3/cytoscape-klay.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The demo normally uses the local cytoscape-klay file, so there should be no problem really. Is this code working for you?

Comment: Yes, your 3 include files made it work.   I didn't find a working demo with those files when I unzipped the github package, but I guess it was there.

Comment: Usually for the main scaffolding of cytoscape.js layouts, I copy the demo.html file (almost all of the demos have these) and change out the static imports with a site like jsDelivr.com or unpkg.com. This way you get the layout and also some example nodes